# Recreating a PendingIntent from another class?

Tags: android

This may be a stupid question. I've created and alarm with a PendingIntent. In a separate class I want to cancel it. I have all the parameters I used to create it - except the context. The alarm was created in myClassAlarm.class and I'm going to cancel it in myService.class.

Does this matter, I assume it does - but its tricky to test with my application.